# Extends AbstractEntity<MyClass> with codemodel

Tags: java, sun-codemodel

Does anyone know how to generate this with CodeModel ??

```
...
public class MyClass extends AbstractEntity<MyClass> { 
...
```

I already have something like this.. almost there..

```
JCodeModel jCodeModel = new JCodeModel();
...
JDefinedClass jClass = jPackage._class("MyClass");
jClass._extends(AbstractEntity.class);
```

How do i make this

```
extends AbstractEntity
```

into

```
extends AbstractEntity<MyClass>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it..

```
JClass jClassExtends = jCodeModel.ref(AbstractEntity.class).narrow(jClass);
jClass._extends(jClassExtends);
```

and the result is :

```
public class MyClass extends AbstractEntity<MyClass>
```